# Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.utils.StringHelper.appendCapitalized(Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I have done nothing with the codebase, and I'm surprised to see the below error.

And I have tried upgrading or downgrading the Gradle wrapper and Gradle build tools.

I'm using Gradle build tools v3.2.1 with Gradle wrapper4.6-all.zip.

Note: Other projects are working fine and even I tried deleted the complete code and cloned a fresh one

Can anyone please help me

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of this one but whenever a network related issue occurs, I restart Android Studio and also restart my internet connection. Make sure you have good connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

update your gradle file.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Comment: Yes, that works. but I can't upgrade now. I really wanna know why this error?